# Excel formula to lookup and match the cases

Tags: excel

I am trying to find the excel formula;

- Sheet 1:  to get employee name details in cell O2 against the employee number in cell G2
- Employee data base details are in Sheet 2 (Column G- Employee number, .... Column N- Location & Column O- Employee name)
- Formula to find the employee name against respective employee numbers and match the location which is available in Sheet 2 column N. In case of duplicates of employee number in multiple locations, it should be mentioned as DUPLICATE.

Thanks & Regards,
Edi

Unable to find the appropriate formula on this

Comment: Try index() and match().